# R as.date error creating date

Tags: r, as.date

I am trying to create a time series of future dates (every day for a 30-year time period, starting in 2020). I was able to create a time series:

```
library(zoo) 
df$Date <- zooreg(1:10958, start = as.Date("2020-01-01")) #assign date
```

But, I was not able to convert the time series to a date using as.date:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format="%Y%m%d")
df$Year <- as.numeric(format(df$Date, format = "%Y"))
f$Month <- as.numeric(format(df$Date, format = "%b"))
df$Day <- as.numeric(format(df$Date, format = "%d"))
```

I continue to get the error:

```
Error in as.Date.default(df$Date, format = "%Y%m%d") : do not know how to 
convert 'df$Date' to class “Date”
```

Comment: The way you've defined `df$Date` is with `1:10958` as the "Data" and the dates as the "Index". Seems like you're expecting they should be reversed?

Comment: The same error results. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like you just want `seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 10958) `. Or just `as.Date("2020-01-01") + 0:10958`